# Codechef and the right triangle by slope method

Tags: c

https://www.codechef.com/problems/RIGHTRI

The Pythagoras theorem question is very easy but I am not able to find out what could be wrong when I am using to do the same by slope method. 
following is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int N,count=0;
    double m1,m2,m3,x1,x2,x3,y1,y2,y3;
    scanf("%d",&N);
    while(N--){
            scanf("%lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf",&x1,&y1,&x2,&y2,&x3,&y3);
            if(x1==x2||x2==x3||x3==x1){
                    if(y1==y2||y2==y3||y3==y1)
                            count++;
            }
            else{
                    //printf("hello");
                    m1=((y1-y2)*(y3-y2))/((x1-x2)*(x3-x2));
                    m2=((y1-y2)*(y1-y3))/((x1-x2)*(x1-x3));
                    m3=((y3-y2)*(y1-y3))/((x3-x2)*(x1-x3));
                    //      printf("%lf %lf %lf\n",m1,m2,m3);
                    if((m1==(-1.000000))||(m2==(-1.000000))||(m3==(-1.000000)))
                            count++;
                }
        }
        printf("%d\n",count);
        return 0;
}
```

**new code**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int N,count=0;
    int m1N,m1D,m2N,m2D,m3N,m3D,x1,x2,x3,y1,y2,y3;
    scanf("%d",&N);
    while(N--){
            scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d",&x1,&y1,&x2,&y2,&x3,&y3);
            if(x1==x2||x2==x3||x3==x1){
                    if(y1==y2||y2==y3||y3==y1)
                            count++;
            }
            else{
                    m1N=((y1-y2)*(y3-y2));
                    m1D=((x1-x2)*(x3-x2));
                    m2N=((y1-y2)*(y1-y3));
                    m2D=((x1-x2)*(x1-x3));
                    m3N=((y3-y2)*(y1-y3));
                    m3D=((x3-x2)*(x1-x3));
                    if((m1N==-m1D)||(m2N==-m2D)||(m3N==-m3D))
                            count++;
            }
    }
    printf("%d\n",count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For some specified input, what results do you expect? And what results do you actually get?

Comment: My guess though is that it has to do with floating point rounding errors. You can't do lot of floating point operations on a computer and expect to get an exact value, it's simply not possible. That means your comparisons against `-1.000000` won't work. You might want to [read this](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm), as it explains the problem and shows some ways how to solve it.

Comment: If you read the question  it states that **coordinates are integer values** . Then why are you bothering with `double`?

Comment: If the above comments are correct, then you should read the coordinates as `int`, and then compute the numerator and denominator separately (using integer math) for each of the slopes. Then check `if(numerator == -denominator)`.

Comment: @user3386109 i tried your way but still something seems to be wrong.

Comment: @NakulVaidya The answer by user007 points out another problem in the code. Since the updated code is not doing divisions anymore, it's safe to get rid of the first `if` statement. For example, the triangle {(0,3) (0,0) (4,0)} will result in `m1N=0` and `m1D=0` and since `0 == -0`, it will be counted as a right triangle. user007's example has `m3N=9` and `m3D=-9`, so that will also be counted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the `if` condition you put at the starting of the `while` loop, to check if any coordinates have the same value.

It is not always necessary that if any 2 points sharing the common x-coordinate, must also be sharing a same y-coordinate to form a right-angled triangle, which you seem to assume in your code. Example take these coordinates::

> (0, 0), (0, 5), (2.5, 2.5)

(I know the problem statement says only integer values, but this was the easiest case that came to mind, and I believe you can form a test case like this with only integer values.)

If we follow, your code then `x1 = x2` but, no y-values are the same and your code does not count this as a right angle triangle, though it is a right angled triangle.

So, the easiest solution would be to remove the first `if` condition, and let the rest of the code run, and you will get an AC.

**EDIT::**

Example with integer coordinates ::

> (0, 0), (0, 6), (3, 3)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit : m1,m2,m3 being the product of slopes.**

What's wrong is your approach I believe, change your code as follows with comments added :

```
//if(x1==x2||x2==x3||x3==x1){ not required,no such property for a right angle triangle
                    //if(y1==y2||y2==y3||y3==y1)
                            //count++;
            //}
            //else{
                    //printf("hello");
                    m1=((y1-y2)*(y3-y2))/((x1-x2)*(x3-x2));
                    m2=((y1-y2)*(y1-y3))/((x1-x2)*(x1-x3));
                    m3=((y3-y2)*(y1-y3))/((x3-x2)*(x1-x3));
                    //      printf("%lf %lf %lf\n",m1,m2,m3);
                    if( m1 == -1 ||m2==-1 || m3*m1==-1 ) //product of slope of two perpendicular lines is -1
                            count++;
```

> Note : by this method you are applying an INT to INT division which
>   might actually trim the exact slope into incorrect values. Insist you
>   to use the double value and then cast it after evaluating the product
>   of slopes.

Comment: Note that `m1`, `m2`, `m3` are *not* the slopes of the three lines.